# Correctly parsing FormData files in node/express without multipart middleware?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, fetch, buffer

I'm trying to parse an http.IncomingMessage object correctly and trying to figure out best-use practices in dealing with different files received from FormData objects. My objective is to NOT use form parsing middleware such as multer/formidable/busboy, etc, although looking through their source code has given me enough hints to sort of get it working so far.

Here's my code:

**Backend**:

```
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    const webkitRegexp = new RegExp('--WebKit');
    let i = 0;
    let body = [];
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body.push(chunk);
        let headerFilter = body[i].toString();
        if (webkitRegexp.test(headerFilter)) console.log(`i: ${i}, t/f: ${webkitRegexp.test(headerFilter)}`);
        i++;
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        let file = Buffer.concat(body);
        fs.appendFile('./test1.pdf', file, "utf8");
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

**Frontend**:

```
(HTML):
<div id="upload"></div>
        <form method="POST" action="/api/upload">
            <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput">
            <button id="fileSubmitButton" type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>


(JS):
fileSubmitButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }
    fetch('/api/upload', options);
});
```

So far, when I upload a file, for example a PDF file, using the above code, it works. It's very crude, but it works. However, I'm sure that I'm not doing it very "cleanly" or correctly. For one, the file size grows with each transfer, because the form headers are being attached at the top of the file:

````
------WebKitFormBoundaryIHdsrd2LUJ3swA55
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test2.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundaryKBIGn3csB55i68XN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="vzw_coi_agreement.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.4
%����
43 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 417824/O 45/E 38624/N 14/T 416844/H [ 416 170]>>
endobj
               
xref
43 6
0000000016 00000 n
0000000586 00000 n
0000000649 00000 n
0000000838 00000 n
0000000947 00000 n
0000000416 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 49/Root 44 0 R/Info 42 0 R/ID[<C7F3B3EAC78D2F720E9C16C3F3E1E7FE><775B5807B229A245A8B09FE97F2C5522>]/Prev 416833>>
startxref
0
%%EOF
             
48 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/I 121/Length 90/S 90>>stream
h�b```f``��
````

As you can see in my code, I was trying to drill down on the exact chunk which contains the header so I could not push it into the body[], however, each chunk contains the headers plus a lot of the beginning data of the PDF file. Is there already a way to parse ONLY the file from the form, and filter the headers out of the chunk data? Do I need to use a different stream reader method other than the request.on('data') method? Maybe request.pipe(body) would offer me a better route? One thought I had would be to convert not only each chunk into a string and run test(), but to iterate through each chunk itself until I found the string I wanted and skip pushing it into body[]. Maybe someone could help me with the code for that, or maybe I can avoid that and there is a better technique altogether.

Again, I know I could just import multer or formidable and be done with it. However, I'm interested in learning how these packages work, and it helps me learn node/JS/express by doing things like this myself. I have found some similar questions on SO, but usually someone responds with "use multer" and that's that. I find working with this raw file and data techniques extremely interesting, and I would appreciate any help with writing some excellent code on how to handle this problem elegantly.

If you need any other information please let me know. Thank you.

Jordan

Comment: Just that you know, your export file grows with every request, because `fs.appendFile` is appending data to it, not rewriting it. Also, if you're processing your data directly with `req.on('data')`, it might make sense to parse boundaries, headers and contents separately :-)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero': To clarify, the file grows after one transfer, from the original file size. For example, if the original file size is 5000B, the transferred file is 5200B. I'm not calling appendFile() again on this same file. This is because of your second point, the headers are being added to the raw data chunk. How do I parse the boundaries, headers, and contents separately when I'm looking at the data chunk as a whole?

Comment: You have to parse the MIME headers so you can get JUST the desired content.  And, you may also have to decode the content properly.  And, heaven forbid if you end up with multi-part bodies, that's even more parsing.  A full MIME parser is a LOT of work if you're really going to study all the relevant specs and be able to handle anything that is sent to you.  You can probably figure out how to make one specific type of response work by studying what you're being sent, but any general sort of MIME parser is a lot of work to get all the bugs out.

Comment: You would probably find it useful to create a list of all the RFCs you need to understand to do proper MIME parsing.  If you actually find all of them, that will give you a rough idea of how much time this could consume to do it right.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for your help everyone.